# IOS initial view controller based on condition retrieved from database

Tags: ios

An iOS app I'm creating shows a setup screen upon first launch which requires data to be written to the database.

Upon launch, I need to access this value form the database.

If it is set, launch main view controller

Else show setup view controller.

As far as I'm aware theres two ways I can do this, programmatically setting it from the `AppDelegate` or using an initial View Controller as a splash screen and performing the look up and segue there.

What would be the best way to approach this? Is it wrong to do a database lookup in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a splash screen is probably the better option as it provides better scope for modification in the future and allows you to update the user on progress. It is fine for the app delegate to run logic to determine how the app starts but you should endeavour to keep the app delegate minimal and focussed.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt that you would get this approved (if your goal is the App Store). Your app delegate needs to create a window, and set a rootViewController to that window before it returns YES in appFinishLaunching:
You simply do not have enough time to check with a server before creating the first viewController and you'll be creating poor interface if you try. I suggest the first ViewController will need to be informing the user that it is checking with the server with an activityIndicator or something. The best :)

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error saying: "[Application] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?" Are you sure this can be done?